# Just made Product Owner with no prior experience and tasked to lead and renovate the whole R&D department, how can I do it?

Tags: management, software-development, work-experience, scrum

The software development team in our company is 90% external and in the hands of a single external company, as well as most of the technical know-how acquired in the last 20 years: almost no internal technical skills have ever been sponsored by our top management.
The de-facto R&D Manager - also CEO of this external company - is highly competent and efficient, but he's often a source of friction in our company due to him interacting freely and directly with our customers - sometimes interfering with other departments such as Customer Service or Sales.
For this reason, after a failed negotiation to buy his consultancy company, he's been gradually ousted from the top management.

When my company was acquired by a large Group, the first choice as Product Owner in the R&D department fell on him, being the most competent person on the product. A year later, however, the role was taken away from him under the excuse of being "just a consultant", but in reality as part of a poorly articulated strategy to reduce his power and grow an internal R&D team. To speed up the process, a limit was also imposed for the first time on how much his company could bill us monthly.

In the absence of anyone more competent, the role of PO was given to me.

After about six years in Customer Service, I moved to software development in the same company, but I only accumulated two years of experience - not exactly what you would call an R&D expert.

Now I find myself in the position of:

- having to lead a team of external senior developers, much more experienced than me
- having to collaborate with the ex-R&D manager in charge of the aforementioned developers, who has been leading the R&D department in the last 20 years, and who was recently stripped of the rank of PO
- since the external team is limited by the monthly budget, and therefore it cannot be reliable for full-time work, having to grow a new internal team by finding a way to hire resources
- having to do it *quickly*, since the ex-R&D Manager is already searching for new customers to leave us as soon as our consultancy contract expires: that would leave R&D completely paralyzed
- having to respond to the needs of the Group, in particular on delivery deadlines and roadmap goals, as a PO
- rapidly acquiring the skills and knowledge I'm lacking about all aspects of the product

Furthermore, many colleagues are progressively leaving the company, riding the wave of discontent generated by the acquisition and feeling the complete absence of motivation from the top management - which has found a new PO (me), hence no need to worry about R&D anymore!

I really feel between the hammer and the anvil: I have never felt the weight of expectations placed on me so much.

I believe being a Product Owner is a great opportunity for my professional growth (with all the new meetings I need to attend, I don't have time to write code anymore, therefore my software development career is forcibly switching to dev team management), but I also feel the chances of success becoming increasingly weaker...

Has anyone ever found himself in such a situation, i.e. leading a whole department without any deep experience in the subject, and if so, how did you manage to get the best out of that position?

Comment: "How would you move in such a situation?" I would be asking for a **very** big pay rise.

Comment: Don't expect to have time to write code any more. Now you will be writing and running policy, programming the company. If you want to "keep your fingers in the pie" you may have to go so on your own time; the executive job is full-time if you want to do it right.

Comment: "How did you get the best out of that position" ... I have to consider that asking too many questions at once. "How do you lead a department" could be, and probably has been, a book if not a business degree.

Answer (score 3):

> In the absence of anyone more competent, the role of PO was given to me. [...] How would you move in such a situation?

Like someone hinted in comments, this is a **big** change in your job responsibilities and your role in the company. Such a big change definitely requires some sort of new contract or re-negotiation from both parts (one where your new responsibilities and tasks are discussed, as well as your raise or new salary).

I suggest you approach your manager/boss, most likely the one who "gave you" this PO role, and discuss it thoroughly.

Your post also triggered some red-flags for me, so I suggest you approach this ASAP and with judgment. Other people leaving doesn't sound good to me, and the fact that the way you wrote your post makes it sound like they just handled you this new role and are hoping "you just take it" is also not good... but I may be reading/assuming more than I should there...

Regardless, if handled well and if this current friction goes away this is indeed a good opportunity for you to grow in your career, so also think about that and if it is a path you want to take (like you said, you'll most likely be programming less and managing more).

Answer (score 0):

Expect to spend a lot of time in meetings and reading reports (and journal articles, if your researchers publish outside) to understand

- What is being worked on
- Who is involved
- What the current status of the effort is
- What it's potential value to the company is
- What it will cost to bring it to product.
- What other things the company would like Research to investigate
- &c

Simply coming up to speed enough to lead is going to take a while. Then you'll have to be ready to trade off priorities, both short and long term. Remember that research needs space to pursue weird ideas without continuously focusing on immediate cost and return -- but that the research budget is limited and if something isn't showing promise after a reasonable amount of effort has been spent you may need to redirect that research.

This is assuming you have a real research department. Relatively few companies can afford one. R is different from R&D; longer time scale, more risk, hopefully more reward on average.

Comment: What does "**&c**" mean ?  "**&c**" is the last item in the list that you provided.

Comment: now nitpicking a bit: It's spelled _et cetera_ ( [et ce·te·ra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Et_cetera) ).. *ducking away.. ;)

Comment: Reposting with tupoghrpiplk errro foxed, since SE won't let us edit comments: The ampersand character, &, is historically a ligature of the Latin "Et" (which is why it means "and"). Thus, "&c" is a less common but legitimate alternative to "etc." as a short form of "et cetera" ("and the others"). Sorry; spent too much time typesetting; I'm indecently fond of ligatures. (@ originated as a ligature of ea for "each",  though we usually call it "at" these days.)

Comment: @keshlam OT I had a Russian colleague who referred to '@' as 'Ear'

Answer (score 0):

The first thing has to be to negotiate your compensation including a "pay out period" upon termination. The risks here are huge and termination is a real possibility along with company failure.

The next thing has to be to sit down with your top management and get a clear definition of the goals for the department. The goals need to be specific, measurable, and for a defined time. This may take some effort as the top management may not have figured out what they really want from the department. You may also sit down with the head of sales and get their ideas of what is needed to keep the company competitive.

After that, you can go back to the people in the department and ask them if those goals are realistic and achievable. If not, you will need to work with your management to get a plan of how to hire in order to achieve the company goals. (And in that process, work with your management to adjust the goals to match reality.) If the goals are achievable, work with your team to break down the company goals into short term team and individual goals and how to provide accountability for those goals.

Repeat over and over again as company goals often change by getting new customers, existing customers giving new demands, and market and financial conditions changing. This is why weekly or monthly meetings with your top management and weekly progress meetings with your team is part of the job.

If company "goals" radically change week to week, then that is a sign that they don't really have goals. You may want to leave when you realize that.